# If GCP access keys publicly exposed in public repo

Tags: google-iam

If I were to opt-in for Disabling access keys that google find/detects in public repos or have public exposure, will I be notified?

Please let me know who and when are notified if this situation were to arise.

I am willing to opt-in for this service.